# Leaflet.js Tiles over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, leaflet

I'm trying to run leaflet.js with a server with SSL but get errors for the file fetch similar to the following:

```
GET https://tile.openstreetmap.org/12/1213/1481.png net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3186) on Github that supposedly got solved by changing the request from

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

to

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'      
}).addTo(map);
```

However, even if I try navigating to the link https://tile.openstreetmap.org/12/1213/1481.png I get an error stating "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID".

Anyone found a solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a certificate error or your urlTemplate might need to be `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey Whoops. Yes, I've tried that and just updated my post. The issue appears to be directly with the certs on the tile.openstreetmap.org servers since even a direct link yields the warning. I'm on Safari/Mac btw.

Answer (score 5):

Try link in this form `https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, *F1LT3R* mentioned about it here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3186

Comment: this worked for me. I just wish i found this comment earlier, just lost 2 hours googling...